# Creating object pipelines using dependency injection (Ninject)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm having some difficulties deciding how best to construct a bi-directional object pipeline using dependency injection (`DI`).

I'm currently experimenting with `Ninject` as a `DI` container.

It is actually more complex than that, because I'm considering binding two pipelines together with an adapter.

The two pipelines are defined by (`ITransport`, `ITransportSink`) and (`IMessageProcessor`, `IMessageProcessorSink`) interface pairs below:

```
public interface ITransport {
  void Connect();
  void Disconnect();
  void Send(byte[] buffer)
  void Receive();
}

public interface ITransportSink {
  void OnConnected();
  void OnDisconnected();
  void OnSent();
  void OnReceived(byte[] data);
}

public interface IMessageProcessor {
  void SendMessage(string message);
  void ReceiveMessage();
}

public interface IMessageProcessorSink {
  void OnMessageSent();
  void OnMessageReceived(string message);
}

public class TcpTransport : ITransport {
  public TcpTransport(
    ISocket socket, 
    ITransportSink sink,
    ...
  ) { }
}

public class Program : IMessageProcessorSink {
  void Run() {
    // Set up serializer as an adapter between transports and message processors
    var serializer = new MessageSerializer();
    var tcpTransport = new TcpTransport(socket, serializer);
    serializer.SetTransport(tcpTransport);
    serializer.SetMessageSink(this);
  }

  void OnMessageReceived(string message) {
    Console.Writeline("Received message {0}", message);
  }
}

public class MessageSerializer : ITransportSink, IMessageProcessor {
  public void OnReceived(byte[] data) {
    // Deserializes message and raises IMessageProcessorSink::OnMessageReceived
    var message = Deserialize(data);
    m_processorSink.OnMessageReceived(message);
  }

  public void SendMessage(string message) {
    // Serializes message to byte and calls ITransport::Send
    byte[] data = Serialize(message);
    m_transport.Send(data);
  }
}

var program = new Program();
program.Run();
```

Question:
How can the pipe lines and adapter (MessageSerializer) be best created using `Ninject`?

Question (advanced):
Now consider that there could be multiple ITransports and multiple IMessageProcessors in the pipelines that the MessageSerializer connects.

Using:

```
m_kernel.Get<IEnumerable<ITransport>>()
```

likely won't handle ordering of the transports properly.
Thus I now need to introduce some new concepts:

```
ITransportPipeline  
ITransportPipelineFactory 
IMessageProcessorPipeline
IMessageProcessorPipelineFactory
```

Setup would then be something like:

```
var transportPipelineFactory = m_kernel.Get<ITransportPipelineFactory>();
var messagePipelineFactory = m_kernel.Get<IMessageProcessorPipelineFactory>();

var transportPipeline = transportPipelineFactory.CreatePipeline();
var messageProcessorPipeline = messagePipelineFactory.CreatePipeline();

var serializer = new MessageSerializer();
transportPipeline.Append(serializer);
messageProcessorPipeline.InsertAt(0,serializer);
```

At this point I'm writing so much manual wiring code, that that `DI` container does not seem to be helping much. Are there `DI` container features or bindings that can help here?

I get the feeling either the design is wrong or this is not a scenario that `DI` containers were intended to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while but I found one way to make it work.
The trick is to wrap the configuration logic in a higher level concept objects constructor:

```
public class AggregatePipeline
{
    private ITransportPipeline m_transportPipelines;
    private IMessageProcessorPipeline m_messagePipeline;
    private MessageSerializer m_serializer;

    public AggregatePipeline(
        ITransportPipeline transportPipeline,
        IMessageProcessorPipeline messagePipeline,
        MessageSerializer serializer)
    {
        transportPipeline.Append(serializer);
        messagePipeline.Prepend(serializer);

        m_transportPipeline = transportPipeline;
        m_messagePipeline = messagePipeline;
        m_serializer = serializer;
    }
}
```

Because each of the items are constructor arguments, no need to have explicit calls to kernel.
Add a couple bindings:

```
Bind<AggregatePipeline>().ToSelf()
    .WithConstructorArgument("transportPipeline", (ctx) =>
        {
            return ctx.Kernel.Get<ITransportPipelineFactory>().CreatePipeline();
        })
    .WithConstructorArgument("messagePipeline", (ctx) =>
        {
            return ctx.Kernel.Get<IMessageProcessorPipelineFactory>().CreatePipeline();
        });

Bind<MessageSerializer>().ToSelf();
```

And then create the outer object via the kernel:

```
m_kernel.Get<AggregatePipeline>();
```

Seems to solve the issue w/o service location anti-pattern.